# What's the C++98 equivalent of the auto iterator reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

My development environment has RHEL 5.8 which does not support GCC 4.8+ modern (C++11+) compilers.  I anticipate that someday we'll get there, so I have a header file where I define macros based on C++11 support levels so I can do something like this:

```
#if defined(CPP11_auto_type_inference) && defined(CPP11_range_based_for_loops)
  for (auto vit : args)
#else
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator vit, vend;
  for (vend=args.end(),vit=args.begin(); vit != vend; ++vit)
#endif
  { // process arguments...
    std::cout << "Processing \"" << *vit << '"' << std::endl;
    . . .
  } // end "process arguments" loop
```

So, what I'm trying to do in C++98 is the equivalent of the iterator **reference** (or is it more accurate to say "a dereferenced iterator"?), like below:

```
for (auto& it : args)
  std::cout << "Processing \"" << it << '"' << std::endl;
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get a dereferenced iterator (or iterator reference) in C++98.  I can simulate, as below:

```
#if defined(CPP11_auto_type_inference) && defined(CPP11_range_based_for_loops)
  for (auto& it : args) {
#else
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator vit, vend;
  for (vend=args.end(),vit=args.begin(); vit != vend; ++vit) {
    std::string it(*vit);
#endif
    std::cout << "Processing \"" << it << '"' << std::endl;
    . . .
  }
```

... but I'm *really hoping* that is not the answer.

What is the C++98 equivalent of `for (auto& it : vec)`, or is it not possible?  Is it only possible to "simulate" it but dereferencing the iterator and creating a copy each iteration?

And if that be the case, is that what is going on "under the covers" with C++11 `auto&` syntax?   (I have to believe this is *not the case*.)  In any case, is it more costly to use `for (auto& it : vec)` than `for (auto it : vec)`?

Thank you in advance for your insight.

Comment: you can read the semantic equivalent for a range-based for on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in the **Explanation** block. except you would have to write out the types instead of auto, and use `.begin()` instead of `std::begin`, and finally of course, no rvalue refs

Comment: Note that your first snippet will print strings in C++11, and char in C++98...

Comment: take a look at [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: FWIW, there's `BOOST_AUTO` and `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: "so I have a header file where I define macros based on C++11 support levels" - also known as the boost library, which until c++11 WAS c++.

Comment: @Jarod42 Didn't understand why it would print char, so tried it:<BR>`  assert(argc > 1 && "Usage: quickcpp arg1 [arg2 [... argN]]");
  std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator vit, vend;
  for (vend=args.end(),vit=args.begin(); vit != vend; ++vit)
    std::cout << "Processing \"" << *vit << '"' << std::endl;`<BR>Output:<BR>`quickcpp Now is the time for all good men...
Processing "Now"
Processing "is"
Processing "the"
Processing "time"
Processing "for"
Processing "all"
Processing "good"
Processing "men..."
`

Comment: @Luv2code: I invert C++11/C++98 in my previous comment :/ . C++11 version prints `char`, as in `auto vit : args`, vit is `std::string` so `*vit` is `char`. In C++98, `vit` is `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator` so `*vit` is `const std::string&`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, okay.  So on a vector of strings `for (auto vit : vec)` is not a string pointer, but a string?  So `auto` is the same *usage* as `auto&`, the only difference is presumably the latter is more efficient.  Okay, I get you.  I thought both the auto and explicit would result in vit being a string-vector iterator (in essence, a string pointer).

Comment: My examples assume if C++11 is supported, the program was compiled with the `-std=c++11` option.  Is there standard macro that gets defined that tells what "standard" (-std=???) was used to build the code?

Answer (score 4):

This has been done before in C++ 98, my favorite solution is Niebler's in [Conditional Love: FOREACH Redux](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html)

To get a taste of the "hackery" involved in doing this take a look at how an "auto_iterator" is defined

```
struct auto_any_base {};

template< class T > struct auto_any :
auto_any_base
{
   auto_any( T const & t ) : item( t ) {}
   mutable T item;
};

template< class Container >
auto_any< typename Container::const_iterator >
begin( Container const & c )
{
   return c.begin();
}
```

> As the name "auto_any" suggests, this is a general mechanism for putting an object of unknown type in automatic storage (i.e. it is not dynamically allocated using new).

Now, to (begin creating) a FOREACH macro we can say:

```
#define BOOST_FOREACH( item, container ) \
   auto_any_base const & iter = begin( container ); \
```

There's working code in the link (and a lot, lot, looooot more to digest when reading this)

Comment: That is a bit over my head, but perhaps a good night's sleep and a second read will help.  But I learned a bit just from what did sink in the first time.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going into too much trouble to emulate C++11 functionality. You can use C++98/03 method for now. They will continue to work when you are able to use a C++11 compiler.

Having said that, you can use:

```
#if defined(CPP11_auto_type_inference) && defined(CPP11_range_based_for_loops)
  for (auto vit : args)
#else
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator viter, vend;
  for (vend=args.end(),viter=args.begin(); viter != vend; ++viter)
  {
     std::string vit = *viter;
#endif
     { // process arguments...
       std::cout << "Processing \"" << vit << '"' << std::endl;
       . . .
     } // end "process arguments" loop
#if defined(CPP11_auto_type_inference) && defined(CPP11_range_based_for_loops)  
#else
  }
#endif
```

If you want to emulate the equivalent of

```
  for (auto& vit : args)
```

you can use:

```
     std::string const& vit = *viter;
```