# Supporting C++98 and C++11 simultaneously

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

I'm starting to rewrite a substantial amount of code that has to work for several OS/compiler combinations. Some support C++11 and others only support C++98/C++03. I'm looking for a way to be able to use *some* C++11 features in the code.

The primary ones I'm interested in are `override`, `noexcept` and `final`. In other words, syntactically small features that don't really have a C++98/03 equivalent. I'm not trying to shoehorn in ranged for loops using `ifdef` like in [What's the C++98 equivalent of the auto iterator reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898302/whats-the-c98-equivalent-of-the-auto-iterator-reference). That's just too ungainly.

My initial thought was to use the preprocessor for something like this:

```
#if __cplusplus > 201103L
#define OVERRIDE override
#else
#define OVERRIDE
#endif
```

Then my function declarations would look like:

```
virtual void myFunction() OVERRIDE;
```

I don't know if products like Boost already have some mechanism for this, but it's irrelevant in my case as I won't have access to Boost or anything similar on some of the OSes. Nor is an OS/compiler upgrade an option either. I either have to do it myself or not do it at all.

Is there a better way to do this? Am I setting myself up for some unknown headache using this method? Also, should I try to use different names for the macros, like `MY_OVERRIDE`, to avoid naming collisions?

Comment: The Qt library already do this so I do not see a problem with that, you can see the header [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h.html#1028). They do a few other checks that you might be interested in that file for different compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you do this?

```
#if __cplusplus > 201103L
#else
#define override
#endif
```

Then your function declarations would look like:

```
virtual void myFunction() override;
```

which is exactly what you want, isn't it?

Comment: The main catch is that it's possible that `override` is used as a variable somewhere in the program.  Using a different naming convention for macros and variables can avoid this.

Comment: That's intended to be forbidden by the C++ standard ([lib.macro.names]/2 pre-C++11, [macro.names]/2 in C++11 onwards) although I guess it's okay if we only apply the '#define' in places where override is not a keyword. So this version should fail on Visual Studio 2012, which does not declare itself as C++11 (i.e. `__cpluscplus` is < 201103), but it does have the 'override' keyword.

Comment: @TBBle: `override` is not a keyword.  See n3337 2.12.  Also see 2.11.  It's an "identifier with special meaning", along with `final`.

Comment: [macro.names]/2 specifically calls out "the identifiers listed in Table 3", which are `override` and `final`. So you're right, it's not a keyword. But it falls under the same prohibition. So do attribute identifiers, for that matter.

Comment: @TBBle is that also true in the '98 standard? The macro would only be defined when compiling under a legacy standard.

Comment: That was my point. It's technically legal because it's checking the standard version (although the mistake from the question was copied, it should be >=), but Visual Studio 2012 onwards _may_ notice this redefinition and raise an error, because they support `override`, and also support the prohibition, even though the pre-C++11 prohibition didn't apply to a compiler-specific magic token.

Answer (score 3):

That is fine, that is an acceptable way to do things.  I see this in a number of code bases, just the way we used to see things like:

```
#ifdef __STDC__
void func(int x)
#else
void func(x)
    int x;
#endif
{
    ...
}
```

I can't imagine that Boost would have something significantly more usable or concise than what you wrote.

You may want to spell override with fewer Rs, however.  `MY_OVERRIDE` is preferred if you are writing a library that other projects will use, otherwise `OVERRIDE` is fine.

P.S. You may be surprised how common support for some of these features is.  For example, Visual Studio 2008 supports `override` just fine, even though `__cplusplus < 201103L`.

Comment: My hinkey keyboard strikes again. Corrrected ;)

Comment: Alas, `__cplusplus < 201103L` still holds true in VS2015 :(